# I can't animate UIView's border color

Tags: objective-c, core-animation

I try to make fade in/out effect for UIView border but it does'nt work.
When try to do the following effect for background color it works perfectly.
Here is a code I developed:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f 
             animations:^ {

                 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
                 [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
                 self.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
                 self.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
                 [UIView commitAnimations];
             } 
             completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
                 [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
                 self.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
                 self.layer.borderWidth = 1.5f;
                 [UIView commitAnimations];
             }];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the answer to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311285/how-do-i-animate-changing-the-border-colour-of-a-uitextfield) you can't animate CALayer properties in a UIView block.