# How do I animate changing the border colour of a UITextField?

Tags: ios, ios5, uitextfield

I infer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762561/how-to-animate-the-background-color-of-a-uilabel/3762950#comment10223132_3762950) question that the following should animate the colour change of my UITextField's border:

```
        [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0f animations:^() {
            myUITextField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
        }];
```

But it doesn't, the border changes colour instantly. Is it obvious what I'm doing wrong?

*Update:* Ok, so trying the following [implicit animation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimatingLayers.html):

```
        [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0f] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
            myUITextField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
        [CATransaction commit];
```

And that doesn't animate either, same effect: it changes colour instantly (as an aside, where's the default for kCATransactionAnimationDuration for layer.borderColor documented?)

Answer (score 6):

I believe that `CALayer` properties are not animatable in a `UIView` animation block. You would need to set up a `CABasicAnimation` and add that animation to the layer instead.

Comment: Oh, of course. I started with the UIView animation block because I was trying to animate the background colour of the UITextField directly, but despite the docs indicating it should, that simply doesn't work.

Comment: ... but, as edited, I can't get an implicit CABasicAnimation to work either.

Comment: Works just fine for me with an explicit animation (`CABasicAnimation`).